# Why don't we have a "common practice" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

When doing programming stuff, one often comes across things could be done many different ways and the decision is matter taste. Some of these things however people have started doing a particular way, just because that's the it's usually done. One could call these *common practices*. A person who has experience in a field could very easily tell what the common practice in a situation is, saving noobs a whole of time wasted trying to decide what choice to make based on nothing. Were I to ask about a common practice in a situation, I feel the question would be closed as opinion based. Could this tag make it clear that what is asked for is the common practice in a situation which is of course well defined.

Comment: Researching different solutions to the same problem is _not_ a waste of time. Blindly following dogma/best practices/common practices is a terrible way to learn.

Answer (score 10):

[common-practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/common-practices) would be a meta tag.

The purpose of tags is to categorize questions, **help people discover interesting questions to answer**. Meta tags are vague and generic; they don't tell you much - if anything at all - about the actual problem presented in the question. Thus, they are pointless.

Furthermore, as you note common practices questions are rarely welcome on Stack Overflow. A tag wouldn't magically change that, as it doesn't do anything to address the problems common practices questions have. If it did anything at all, it would be to help us close those questions quicker.

Further reading: [The Death of Meta Tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

Comment: The meta-post about these specific type of meta-tags I like most: ["While you may be an exemplary, clear-thinking, individual, who uses the term best practice in a constructive manner, ..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing/142354#142354)

Comment: It would be a great honey pot for primarily opinion based questions though. #sarcasm